# How to determine which of 2 common/neutral wires belong to my hot wire

Tags: wiring

I am rewiring my garage.  There are 3 circuits in the garage coming in through 1 conduit from the panel.

I carefully diagramed the current state but then in a fit of stupidity, disconnected my source conduit with 6 wires (no ground) and now am unsure how to pair up my common wires with their respective hot wires.  I have a multimeter.  Is it as simple as turning on one of the circuits and testing the hot/common wire combinations?

Answer (score 2):

I turn on every possible load, and put night lights or something into every receptacle.   Then I start back at the panel or wherever I have separated conductors.     I unhook all hots and neutral going into a particular conduit.

Then I measure the resistance of each hot against each neutral.  I aim to see a simple answer.  If I do not, then I troubleshoot the crossed neutrals until it is simple.  Then I tape those pairs together where they enter.  Without this first step, the potential of a crossed neutral will make everything else hard.

If I was at an intermediate point, I then hook up one pair of wires going back to the panel, and go to the panel and test out which pair it is.  Again with the tape.  Rinse wash repeat.

I won't bother marking wires in conduit if it's obvious; like a 12 AWG MWBC blue-blue-white and also a 10 AWG heater run red-red.

Comment: Thank you.  I am at what i believe is your intermediate state.  I have the 6 unpaired wires exposed from the source conduit coming from the panel.  so, if i turn on one breaker, i should be able to identify its hot/neutral pair using my multimeter, correct?  if i pair the multimeter to an unpaired neutral it will be obvious somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what is the differential switch governing the hot wire, you can just switch off any other differential but that, and try with a simple lamp between the hot and each neutral. The one paired to your hot will just power the light, whereas the one impared with your hot will keep the light off.
(Note: corrected some errors)

Comment: Thank you - that added to @Harper answer makes things much clearer.